# Printing the Driver/Customer list in Microsoft Dynamic RMS-based software. Customer/Driver Name is getting duplicated for each product we use

Tags: xml

I need a help from the community to sort this problem. We are using a old system and I couldn't find any support from the developer. So I need the community support to sort this one out. We are using Microsoft Dynamic RMS based software to provide the front end customer registration.

When we want to create a customer list who bought the products the list is duplicating the customer name depending on the number of product we used specifically in the Run. Example in the attachment.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ompj4.png)

And this DriverList producing is using XML coding as below

```
<!-- Report *** List *** -->
<Report>
    <Name>List</Name>
    <DataSource>
      <ConnectionString>Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=M0ndaY2008;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=ROC_RMS;Data Source=roc-server2</ConnectionString>
      <RecordSource>PARAMETERS runid long; rocsprptrundrivers [runid]</RecordSource>
    </DataSource>
    <Layout>
      <Width>10545</Width>
      <MarginLeft>1250</MarginLeft>
      <MarginTop>600</MarginTop>
      <MarginRight>1250</MarginRight>
      <MarginBottom>600</MarginBottom>
      <Orientation>1</Orientation>
    </Layout>
    <Groups>
      <Group>
        <Name>Group 1</Name>
        <GroupBy>TeamName</GroupBy>
      </Group>
    </Groups>
    <Sections>
      <Section>
        <Name>Detail</Name>
        <Height>300</Height>
      </Section>
      <Section>
        <Name>Header</Name>
        <Type>1</Type>
        <Height>600</Height>
      </Section>
      <Section>
        <Name>Footer</Name>
        <Type>2</Type>
        <Height>285</Height>
      </Section>
      <Section>
        <Name>Page Header</Name>
        <Type>3</Type>
        <Height>1425</Height>
      </Section>
      <Section>
        <Name>Page Footer</Name>
        <Type>4</Type>
      </Section>
      <Section>
        <Name>Booking Header</Name>
        <Type>5</Type>
        <Height>315</Height>
        <ForcePageBreak>256</ForcePageBreak>
      </Section>
      <Section>
        <Name>Group 0 Footer</Name>
        <Type>6</Type>
      </Section>
    </Sections>
    <Fields>
      <Field>
        <Name>DataField32</Name>
        <Section>0</Section>
        <Text>IIF(NickName&lt;&gt;"",NickName,FullName)</Text>
        <Calculated>-1</Calculated>
        <Left>1815</Left>
        <Width>2865</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Align>6</Align>
        <CanGrow>-1</CanGrow>
        <CanShrink>-1</CanShrink>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>DataField34</Name>
        <Section>5</Section>
        <Text>TeamName</Text>
        <Calculated>-1</Calculated>
        <Width>1770</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Align>0</Align>
        <CanGrow>-1</CanGrow>
        <CanShrink>-1</CanShrink>
        <Font>
          <Bold>-1</Bold>
        </Font>
        <Anchor>2</Anchor>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>DataField</Name>
        <Section>0</Section>
        <Text>Kart</Text>
        <Calculated>-1</Calculated>
        <Left>4785</Left>
        <Width>1500</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Align>6</Align>
        <CanGrow>-1</CanGrow>
        <CanShrink>-1</CanShrink>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>Label</Name>
        <Section>3</Section>
        <Text>Driver Name</Text>
        <Left>1822</Left>
        <Top>1140</Top>
        <Width>2865</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Font>
          <Bold>-1</Bold>
        </Font>
        <Anchor>2</Anchor>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>Label1</Name>
        <Section>3</Section>
        <Text>Team Name</Text>
        <Top>1140</Top>
        <Width>1725</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Font>
          <Bold>-1</Bold>
        </Font>
        <Anchor>2</Anchor>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>Label2</Name>
        <Section>3</Section>
        <Text>Kart</Text>
        <Left>4785</Left>
        <Top>1140</Top>
        <Width>1500</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Font>
          <Bold>-1</Bold>
        </Font>
        <Anchor>2</Anchor>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>Label3</Name>
        <Section>3</Section>
        <Text>Race:</Text>
        <Top>570</Top>
        <Width>1155</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Font>
          <Bold>-1</Bold>
        </Font>
        <Anchor>2</Anchor>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>DataField1</Name>
        <Section>3</Section>
        <Text>run_name</Text>
        <Calculated>-1</Calculated>
        <Left>1140</Left>
        <Top>570</Top>
        <Width>1860</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Align>0</Align>
        <CanGrow>-1</CanGrow>
        <CanShrink>-1</CanShrink>
        <Anchor>2</Anchor>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>Label4</Name>
        <Section>3</Section>
        <Text>Event:</Text>
        <Top>285</Top>
        <Width>1155</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Font>
          <Bold>-1</Bold>
        </Font>
        <Anchor>2</Anchor>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>DataField2</Name>
        <Section>3</Section>
        <Text>event_name</Text>
        <Calculated>-1</Calculated>
        <Left>1140</Left>
        <Top>285</Top>
        <Width>1860</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Align>0</Align>
        <CanGrow>-1</CanGrow>
        <CanShrink>-1</CanShrink>
        <Anchor>2</Anchor>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>Label5</Name>
        <Section>3</Section>
        <Text>Resource:</Text>
        <Width>1155</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Font>
          <Bold>-1</Bold>
        </Font>
        <Anchor>2</Anchor>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>DataField3</Name>
        <Section>3</Section>
        <Text>res_name</Text>
        <Calculated>-1</Calculated>
        <Left>1140</Left>
        <Width>1860</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Align>0</Align>
        <CanGrow>-1</CanGrow>
        <CanShrink>-1</CanShrink>
        <Anchor>2</Anchor>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>DataField4</Name>
        <Section>3</Section>
        <Text>startSched</Text>
        <Calculated>-1</Calculated>
        <Format>Date</Format>
        <Left>3510</Left>
        <Top>285</Top>
        <Width>1065</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Align>0</Align>
        <CanGrow>-1</CanGrow>
        <CanShrink>-1</CanShrink>
        <Anchor>2</Anchor>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>Line2</Name>
        <Section>3</Section>
        <Top>1410</Top>
        <Width>6570</Width>
        <BorderStyle>1</BorderStyle>
        <LineSlant>2</LineSlant>
        <Anchor>2</Anchor>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>DataField6</Name>
        <Section>2</Section>
        <Text>count(kart)</Text>
        <Calculated>-1</Calculated>
        <Left>1275</Left>
        <Width>1155</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Align>0</Align>
        <CanGrow>-1</CanGrow>
        <CanShrink>-1</CanShrink>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>DataField7</Name>
        <Section>2</Section>
        <Text>Total Drivers:</Text>
        <Calculated>-1</Calculated>
        <Width>1290</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Align>0</Align>
        <CanGrow>-1</CanGrow>
        <CanShrink>-1</CanShrink>
        <Font>
          <Bold>-1</Bold>
        </Font>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>Label6</Name>
        <Section>3</Section>
        <Text>Run Start Date and Time:</Text>
        <Left>3510</Left>
        <Width>2490</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Font>
          <Bold>-1</Bold>
        </Font>
        <Anchor>2</Anchor>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>Line</Name>
        <Section>5</Section>
        <Top>270</Top>
        <Width>6570</Width>
        <BorderStyle>1</BorderStyle>
        <LineSlant>2</LineSlant>
        <Anchor>2</Anchor>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>Line1</Name>
        <Section>0</Section>
        <Top>300</Top>
        <Width>6570</Width>
        <BorderStyle>1</BorderStyle>
        <LineSlant>2</LineSlant>
        <Anchor>2</Anchor>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>DataField8</Name>
        <Section>3</Section>
        <Text>startSched</Text>
        <Calculated>-1</Calculated>
        <Format>Time</Format>
        <Left>4035</Left>
        <Top>570</Top>
        <Width>540</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Align>0</Align>
        <CanGrow>-1</CanGrow>
        <CanShrink>-1</CanShrink>
        <Anchor>2</Anchor>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>DataField9</Name>
        <Section>3</Section>
        <Text>endSched</Text>
        <Calculated>-1</Calculated>
        <Format>Time</Format>
        <Left>4890</Left>
        <Top>570</Top>
        <Width>810</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Align>0</Align>
        <CanGrow>-1</CanGrow>
        <CanShrink>-1</CanShrink>
        <Anchor>2</Anchor>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>Label7</Name>
        <Section>3</Section>
        <Text>From</Text>
        <Left>3510</Left>
        <Top>570</Top>
        <Width>495</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Anchor>2</Anchor>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>Label8</Name>
        <Section>3</Section>
        <Text>To</Text>
        <Left>4605</Left>
        <Top>570</Top>
        <Width>240</Width>
        <Height>285</Height>
        <Anchor>2</Anchor>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name>TitleLbl</Name>
        <Section>1</Section>
        <Text>Run Drivers</Text>
        <Width>9360</Width>
        <Height>600</Height>
        <Align>6</Align>
        <ForeColor>128</ForeColor>
        <Font>
          <Name>Times New Roman</Name>
          <Size>20.25</Size>
          <Bold>-1</Bold>
        </Font>
      </Field>
    </Fields>
  </Report>
</Reports>
```

Appreciate if someone can help me out to make the list either

1. List can be produce according to the product customer purchased
   if that is hard
2. No Product at all just the customer name rest of the information but without duplicating.

Thank you in advance